# how to Split large string value to individual data in java?

Tags: java

I have a large  string  where each data being separated by `";"`  symbol  which is the better solution in Java to split the  string so that individual  data can be taken? Any solution other than `StringToknizer` class  in Java?

Answer (score 4):

Just use [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

```
  String[] resultArray = yourString.split(";");
```

That gives you the array of spitted `string's`. You just iterate the array to get individual strings.

```
 for (String string : resultArray) {
        System.out.println(string);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the String#split method

```
String string = "004;034556";
String[] parts = string.split(";");
String part1 = parts[0]; // 004
String part2 = parts[1]; // 034556
```

To test beforehand if the string contains a ;

```
if (string.contains(";")) {
// Split it.
} else {
throw new IllegalArgumentException("String " + string + " does not contain ;");
}
```